# Conditional Screen in TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, create-react-native-app

My router is this. Is there a way where a variable will tell what screen should display?

```
export const HomeNavigator = TabNavigator({
    ...
    Search:{
        screen: usertype == 1? Customer : Handyman,
    },
    ...
});

export const RootStack = StackNavigator({
    Login: {screen: Login}
    Home:{screen: HomeNavigator},
    ...
},{
    headerMode: 'none'
});

export default RootStack;
```

After the user logged in his account, the application will check his account type. Then his account type will tell what screen should display in the **Search tab**:

> if the **user's account type is 1** the screen that should display is **customer.js**
>
> if the **user's account type is 2** the screen that should display is **Handyman.js**

Comment: Could you please provide more info on the problem/use-case you are trying to solve?

Comment: is it okay now?

Answer (score 0):

I will show you workflow of my package, and feel free to ask if you still confusing,

in `router.js` (handling screen):

```
const Tab =  TabNavigator({
  Customer : {
    screen: Customer,
  }
});

const TabLogged =  TabNavigator({
  Handyman: {
    screen: Handyman,
  }
});
// here's the key to handle which account is logged
export const Check = SwitchNavigator({
  Auth: Auth,
  Account1: Tab,
  Account2: TabLogged
})
```

create `Auth.js` to check which account is logged:

```
..import

class foo extends React.component{
  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.navigation.navigate(usertype == 1 ? 'Account1' : 'Account2');
  }

  render(){
    <View>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
    </View>
  }
}
```

and in your `app.js` or `index.js` :

```
..import check variable from router.js

class app extends Component{
  render() {
    return <check/>;
  }
}
```

Comment: so I need 2 tab navigators with both same screens but only differ in **search tab**?